# How to inject properly a service in WCF service and other services by using SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, wcf, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

If there are two WCF services defined like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class WcfService1: IWcfService1
{
     private IService1 _service1;
     public WcfService(IService1 service1){
         _service1 = service1;
     }
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class WcfService2: IWcfService2
{
     private IService2 _service2;
     public WcfService(IService2 service2){
         _service2 = service2;
     }
}
```

and if the Service2 is injected in Service1, which is the best way to register Service2 with SimpleInjector?

like this

```
container.RegisterPerWcfOperation<IService1, Service1>();    
container.RegisterPerWcfOperation<IService2, Service2>();
```

or like this

```
container.RegisterPerWcfOperation<IService1, Service1>();    
container.Register<IService2, Service2>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

The container is configured like this:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WcfOperationLifestyle();
```

Comment: The answer completely depends on what you need. Do you need to have exactly one instance of Service2 for the duration of a single request?

Comment: When I request a WcfService1 endpoint, I need one instance of Service2 which should be destroyed after the call. When I request a WcfService2 endpoint, I also need one instance of Service2 which should also be destroyed after that call.

Comment: You can even register them as Transient (the default lifestyle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the use of the (old) extension methods such as `RegisterPerWcfRequest` is discouraged, since the availability of the new `Lifestyle.Scoped` property. `Lifestyle.Scoped` gives a simpler, more readable and more flexible model of registering scoped instances, while the same underlying lifestyle is used, since you set that through `Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle`.

Furthermore, since each WCF call to a service runs in its own request, a new scope exist and each service will get its own instance of `Service2`, no matter whether you register it as `Transient` or `Scoped`. Only if you register it as `Singleton` you will see the same instance of `Service2` be reused over requests; in fact, with `Singleton` there will be only one instance of `Service2` for the lifetime of your WCF service.

The real question here is, if `WcfService1` or `WcfService2` depend on other classes that directly or indirectly depend on `Service2` as well, must the same instance of `Service2` be used during that request, or is it okay to have multiple instances of `Service2` during that single request? If multiple instances is okay, you can register it as `Transient`, otherwise as `Scoped`.

The following registrations will do the trick if you want your components to have the transient lifestyle.

```
container.Register<IService1, Service1>();    
container.Register<IService2, Service2>();
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Thanks Steven!